# Is it good practice to set variables to null when they are no longer needed?

Tags: javascript, null

I have seen javascript values set to `null` at the end of a function.
Is this done to **reduce memory usage** or just to **prevent accidental usage** elsewhere?

Is there a good case for doing this. If so when?

```
var myValue;
.
.
.
myValue = null;
```

Comment: Is there a case for setting to null or using delete for performance or optimizing memory usage

Comment: The are some rare situations when you might want to set null to a variable or object property, to allow GC to free the memory (setting to null doesn't mean that memory will be freed immediately).  Let's say you have a SPA which actively uses cache with some html data. Variable which holds cache is accessible from closure which will live during all running time. And maybe you don't need this in some state of application no more, so mark it with null.

Comment: But I believe that usually such situations happen because of bad app design.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It wouldn't make any difference setting a local variable to `null` at the end of the function because it would be removed from the stack when it returns anyway.

However, inside of a closure, the variable will *not* be deallocated.

```
var fn = function() {

   var local = 0;

   return function() {
      console.log(++local);
   }

}

var returned = fn();

returned(); // 1
returned(); // 2
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fSmgT/).

When the inner function is returned, the outer variable's scope will live on, accessible to the returned inner function.

Comment: so setting to null at the end of a function is redundent?

Comment: unless the variable was not declared using "var"

Comment: @bob ...and the variable is not local to the function.

Comment: There may be some specific issues relating to variables referencing DOM elements in IE. Take [this code for example](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.6.2/src/support.js#L247-248) from jQuery source where a number of such variables are set to `null`.

Comment: Have you considered closures?

Answer (score 20):

There was an issue with iE and circular references involving DOM elements. This was usually created when attaching listeners as follows:

```
function doStuff() {
   var el = document.getElementById('someID');
   el.onclick = function() {
     // has closure to el
   };

   // remove reference to element
   el = null;
}
```

When *doStuff* ia called, the anonymous function attached to the element has a closure back to the element - a circular reference. In older versions of IE this caused a memory leak so the solution was to set *el* to *null* (or anything other than *el*) to break the circular reference after the assignment to `el.onclick`.

The second reason to use it is similar - if a function has a closure that keeps a reference a large object that might otherwise be garbage collected, then it may be useful to remove the reference so that the object can be cleaned up:

```
var someFunction = (function() {
  var x = reallyBigObject;
  // do stuff that uses reallyBigObject

  // Remove reference to reallyBigObject if it's no longer required
  x = null;

  return function() {
    // closure to x is unavoidable, but reference to reallyBigObject isn't required
  }
}());
```

So if the function returned to *someFunction* doesn't actually need to reference *reallyBigObject*, then the reference can be removed so the closure doesn't keep it from being garbage collected unnecessarily.

Note that you can't prevent the closure to variables in scope, but you can modify their values.

This stuff usually isn't much of an issue unless you are keeping pages open for a long time and doing lots of AJAX and adding and removing lots of DOM nodes. But it's probably a good habit to remove references to objects in closures where they aren't needed.

Comment: In your second example, do you need the second `var` with `x`?

Comment: How will you execute the 'x = null;' line if you return something before that? you will never reach that line of code.

Comment: Ah yes, my oversight.

Answer (score 3):

No it isn't. Every local variable is deleted after the end of a function.

Comment: I wonder why someone downvoted my answer which was correct. Please leave a comment where I was mistaken.

Comment: because we are talking about genereally about asigning to null here in the question also no mention of local var or global

Comment: @bob wrote "at the end of a function" so I assumed that question was about local variables. Accepted answer tells almost the same but in other words. Read with understanding. Oh, and did you downvoted too now?

Answer (score -2):

Yes very much so. 
Especially if the variable has some secret information such as a returned password.

As soon as you use the variable declare it as null or "" because active variables in js can be read using inspect element.

```
var password = $('#password').val();
```

After evaluating variable password reset it to "". If you do not the value can be accessed by picking any of your existing html items such as a button and using inspect element to add the attribute code

```
onclick = "javascript:alert(password);"
```

Resetting the variable password to null will keep your password information safe.

```
var password = $('#password').val();
//do what you want to do with variable password
password = null;
```

Comment: You can see the value of any variable in js at any time during execution with the debugger that's built into the browser.